# Is there a way for an Excel workbook to self-destruct after user has entered wrong password 3x?

Tags: excel, password-protection, self-destruction

I know that an Excel workbook can be password protected.  Is there a way to configure an Excel workbook to self-destruct or lock-out further attempts after a password has been entered incorrectly 3x?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set a reference in the excel reference library by going to:

tools -> references -> "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"

(while in vba menu)

Next you would modify your code to look something like this:

```
Sub DeleteModule()

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim passwordAttempt As Int
passwordAttempt = 0

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ModuleName")

password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password Protected")

Select Case password
    Case Is = False
        'do nothing
    Case Is = "easy"
        'do something
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
    passwordAttempt = passwordAttempt + 1
End Select

if passwordAttempt == 3 Then
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
end if

End Sub
```

I'm not familiar with the proper syntax for setting a password, and I just used [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/protect-macro.html) as a reference.

If you need a reference for the self deleting part, you can look [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

Comment: And if you refuse to enable macros on opening?